# State sharing and deletion in model inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.6

I have a Django 1.6 model structure where instances share a common model instance as a subclass.

[image: inheritance]

In database terms, there is a row for `A` a row for `B` and a row for `C` using the `parent_link` for ids.

When calling `.delete()` on `C'` the row for `A` and `C` is deleted but there is an orphan record for `B`. Instantiating `A` directly and calling delete will cascade the delete to `B` and `C` instances. How can I, in the simplest way, ensure deleting an instance of `B` or `C` will delete both the parent and sibling state?

Deleting an instance of A causes linked instances of B and C to be deleted. Deletion of B causes B and A deletion. Deletion of C causes C and A deletion.

How can I have it such that deletion of any A, B or C instance deletes all other instances regardless of the instance delete() is being called on?

As a side note, all instances appear to be deleted, so when calling `.delete()` at `C'` it appears that the base state and `B'` are deleted but infact the row for `B'` will persist and not appear in queries until another base instance is created where the `PK` aligns. In that case, `B'` re-appears from the dead.

Here's the classes:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # Fields here

class B(A):
    a_ptr = models.OneToOneField(A, parent_link=True)
    # More fields

class C(A):
    a_ptr = models.OneToOneField(A, parent_link=True)
    # More fields

# Code
shared_state = A()
shared_state.save()
sharer_b = B(a_ptr=shared_state.id)
charer_c = C(a_ptr=shared_state.id)
sharer_b.save()
sharer_c.save()

# Objective, this should delete all rows for the above?
sharer_c.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either override your [models `delete()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects) or use the [`post_delete` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-delete). NB : links are to the current release doc, but all this worked the same in 1.6.

Comment: The issue I am having with 1.6 where 2 instances share a common instance (B and C instances sharing an A) is that deleting C deletes A however B's row still exists but is orphaned an inaccessible.